Magento 2 : Media Gallery returns 404 Error Page and Images not uploading
As I click on Media Gallery tab inside content tab, it shows 404 error page. The default url also changed. The current url is : mydomain.com/admin/media_gallery/media/index/ -- while it should have been mydomain.com/admin/media_gallery/index/.
I have invested a week for a solution for no success.
Also images aren't uploading.
